# Calculated Field Returning Results Based On IF Statement

Tags: calculated-column

Here is the current IF statement string that I have; however the results are not providing what I want... In essence the formula is working but not entirely... For all statements true, I want the related result to display in the calculated column. Right now, only the first result is showing... For example, I am expecting to see:  Phone System, ACT!, F5 Pool Node, etc. in the calculated column results but only seeing "Phone System" displaying.
[image]
All fields are a drop-down menu field providing the choice of either Yes or No from the field. These are not checkboxes or radial button fields.

Comment: Start of by pasting the Formula in notepad, add plenty of linebreaks and tabs to format your code. You can paste the formula in SP, it will ignore all formatting. Add an extra tab in front of each line and paste your code in this post so we can actually read what your trying to do (no one is going to try and understand what you posted now)

Comment: If you want to see output like  Phone System, ACT!, F5 Pool Node you'd need to concatenate together, you just have a bunch of ifs evaluating field values. I'm guessing you are seeing what you are seeing because the first thing evaluates to true and ends.

Comment: Thanks Eric... you appear to be following where I am trying to go with this...  I am now trying to CONCATENATE the IF statement formula above and no changes are occurring... still only seeing the first IF statement response displaying when in my test example the entire formula should return all 19 items listed... I am wanting to see all items listed one below the other (with line breaks after each one)... So still stumped. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=
IF([Phone Sys Completed]="Yes","Phone System<br/>","")
&
IF([ACT Completed]="Yes","ACT<br/>","")
&
IF([F5 Pool Completed]="Yes","F5 Pool Node<br/>","")
```

... and so forth.

Calculated field settings:

[image]

Results:

[image]

Comment: SP is not liking that... but the following (or above) is accepted but not returning the correct results...

Comment: Are they checkbox fields?

Comment: No they are not checkboxes... all of the fields in question are a drop-down field for the user to select either Yes or No... In this particular calculation, do they need to be checkboxes or radio buttons for a more "truer" TRUE/FALSE situation?

Comment: I had a typo... the first field should be `[Phone Sys Completed]` instead of with the full word "System," right? I'll edit it for that, but otherwise this formula works for me. SharePoint accepted it fine. So check that my field names match yours.

Comment: That's not the issue... it is already corrected in the current formula as I validated that already... but it is still giving back the error of #VALUE!.. SharePoint accepts the formula but the results are still showing the #VALUE!...

Comment: I'll add screenshots of the results I get with the formula above as well as of my calculated field settings.

Comment: @T.Adams, if you still can't get these results, let's start a chat and we can walk through some debugging steps.

Comment: you are a saint!! It is finally working... touchy little booger of a formula... one quotation or comma missing and it drives one crazy... Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Cool. Mark my answer as right, if you don't mind. Also, in the future, when I'm really really struggling with a formula, I break it up into little tiny chunks, and piece them together until I get an error or an invalid result. That way I know what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Okay... I am figuring this out after reading a few postings about IF statement limitations in calculated fields... (something about only 7 IF statements in groups)... and how to adjust for that... That allowed me to modify the entire formula to get it to return all the appropriate line items based on them being "Yes" or "No"... In my test example, all 19 answers should return which is what is occurring now... However, I now need to figure out how to get a "line break" or return between each response so that I see a stacked list response...

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Can anyone in this discussion board provide guidance on how to get line breaks into the formula so that it displays a stacked list of expected results?

Comment: Add <br/> to your calculated field, then return the calculated field as a number instead of a single line of text.

Comment: thanks Erin...  tried adding <br/> at the end of each IF statement but it didn't like it... also I updated the image snapshot of the formula to the current version prior to your comment... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you still getting only one value?

Comment: yes currently I am only getting the first value returned even though all values are selected as "Yes"... and if I remove the ," " from the end of each IF statement, then all values return even though the formula as it shows above is accepted currently... if the IF statement does not equal "Yes" then I want it to return nothing or a blank and then assess the next statement and so on... A little frustrating to say the least... Tnx

Comment: What's happening is that you've told it if the statement is true, to just return that first value and do nothing else. I'll post a solution for you.

Comment: Okay Erin...  someone else offered a solution that was supposed to support the formula returning all as CONCATENATE without having that included in the formula... so curious to see what your solution is... thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
 =
 IF([Phone System Completed]="Phone System<br/>","")
 &
 IF([ACT Completed]="ACT<br/>","")
 &
 IF([F5 Pool Completed]="F5 Pool Node<br/>","")
```

Comment: Please consider adding some description along with the code.

Comment: Hello Asad... please read through the entire thread of discussion as I believe I have provided enough description as to what the intended results are.  Thnx